# "git svn" showing many removed svn tags

Tags: git, git-svn

A svn repository I cloned, had old useless tags deleted, but now after cloning repo with git svn, I can see every of these removed tags in remote tags.

How can this be possible ? Is there a way to tell git svn to not create references to deleted remote svn tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git svn` tracks the whole history of a SVN repository, from the revision 1, unless you limit the range of fetched revisions via `-r` option. From other hand once the history is fetched, it's remembered from where to start so you can remove unneeded entries from `.git/refs/...` (and perhaps `.git/packed-refs` and `git/svn...`)